# How to calculate sides and degrees of triangle

Tags: trigonometry, triangles

So I understand that we can derive the degrees from a triangle with

$$TAN^{-1}\left(\frac{AB}{CB}\right)= A^o (degree)$$

But this only applies on a Right Triangle.
In the next example I want to get value of $DF$ and all of the degrees in the triangle.

[image]

I can't seem to go any further, but I have done other Right Triangles loads of times.

This is what I have:

Split E so that we have 2 new smaller triangles, where EF and G (G is 90 degrees from E. Then DEG is on E:

$$140^0 - 90^0 = 50^0$$

And we know DE and EF.
But from here it seems i'm lost.

[image]

Comment: For DF use the cosine rule.  For the other two angles, use the tangent rule.

Answer (score 1):

For DF you can use *cosine law*:
$$
\text{DF}²= \text{ED}² +  \text{EF}² - 2\cdot\text{ED}\cdot\text{EF}\cdot\cos\text{DÊF}
\\
\text{DF}²= 3² +  4² - 2\cdot3\cdot4\cdot\cos140^o
$$

For the angles you can use *sine law*:
$$
\frac{\text{DF}}{\sin140^o}=\frac{\text{ED}}{\sin\text{E}\hat{\text{F}}\text{D}}=\frac{\text{EF}}{\sin\text{E}\hat{\text{D}}\text{F}}
$$